# Blender evee rendered image plane blurry

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I imported an image using add images as planes. Rendering in evee. Rendered result is blurry. How to get it sharp? Sharp should be the standard without having to change options… [image]

[image: original]

Answer (score 1):

I provide the solution myself. Change image interpolation in the material from linear to closest.